# Downloading raw text from webpage

Tags: html, r, download

I'm looking to download all of the data from this webpage:

```
https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/la/la.data.64.County
```

If you open it, as you can see, a bunch of text data pops up, but the page freezes pretty quickly. The normal way I would do this is to :

```
1: ctrl+a
2: ctrl+c
3: ctrl+v into a text editor or excel
4: import that file into R
```

Since the page becomes unresponsive for me almost immediately, I am unable to do what I normally would.

Any ideas?

Comment: Data is very big but seems to work with `fread`, `df <- fread('https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/la/la.data.64.County')`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with this data in R, you could use `fread` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread('https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/la/la.data.64.County')
head(df)

#              series_id year period value footnote_codes
#1: LAUCN010010000000003 1990    M01   6.4               
#2: LAUCN010010000000003 1990    M02   6.6               
#3: LAUCN010010000000003 1990    M03   5.8               
#4: LAUCN010010000000003 1990    M04   6.6               
#5: LAUCN010010000000003 1990    M05   6.0               
#6: LAUCN010010000000003 1990    M06   7.0
```

The data is very big but seems to import directly into R session.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curl` (linux)

```sh
curl https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/la/la.data.64.County -o data.txt
```

If you are on windows maybe one of this [alternatives](https://superuser.com/questions/299754/wget-curl-alternative-native-to-windows) works for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Inspect the current page

[image]

2. Write `document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerHTML;`

[image]
 3. Click on "copy"

[image]
And now paste it in notepad or something.